# Cassandra - Datacenter data segregation

Tags: database, security, cassandra

I am setting up an Apache Cassandra cluster and I want to segregate certain data to only certain datacenters. I know I can limit where the data is stored via replication factor, but that is not enough.
I have the keyspaces DC1DATA, DC2DATA, ALL, and I want my DC1 data to be

- A) stored in DC1 - solved via replication factor
- B) inaccessible from DC2 (like you cannot run a select statement even as admin user)

And I want both datacenter having access to the "ALL" keyspace.
Can I do that somehow?

This is what I am doing for setting up the keyspaces (example had 1 node x datacenter, total 2 nodes):

```
CREATE KEYSPACE dc1data 
  WITH REPLICATION = { 
   'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 
   'dc1' : 1 
  } ;

  CREATE KEYSPACE dc2data 
  WITH REPLICATION = { 
   'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 
   'dc2' : 1 
  } ;

  CREATE KEYSPACE all 
  WITH REPLICATION = { 
   'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 
   'dc1' : 1,
   'dc2' : 1 
  } ;
```

but I can still connect to any node in DC1 and do

```
cqlsh> use dc2data;
cqlsh:dc2data> create table if not exists test (
  name         text,
  lastname     text,
  primary key ((lastname),name)
);
cqlsh:dc2data> insert into test (name, lastname) values ('Homer','Simpson');
cqlsh:dc2data> select * from test;

 lastname  | name
 ----------+----------
   Simpson |    Homer
```

That is what I want to avoid: seeing the dc2data keyspace from dc1, at all. Is that possible? Even to admin users?

Comment: Curious on why such a use case?

Comment: the separation is geographical, different countries. there are contractual obligation on some data and some are application data that need to be shared.

Comment: Can it better served with different clusters then?

Comment: it's the direction I'm currently going but it would be nice to avoid the overhead.